# MultiPart File Upload with Quarkus / Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, resteasy, quarkus

I am trying to build a multi-part file upload REST route in Quarkus (using Kotlin), but having issues with the route mapping.

From the Client side I am posting a form that contains a text value and a file value.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("text", text);
formData.append("file", files[0]);

fetch('http://localhost:8080/data', {
   method: 'POST',
   body: formData
})
```

From the serverside, I am trying to retrieve the values as follows.

```
class FormData(@FormParam("text") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) var text:String,
              @FormParam("file") @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) var file:InputStream)

@Path("/data")
class FormUploadResource {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    fun upload(@MultipartForm form:FormData) {
        println(form.text)
        println(form.file)
    }
}
```

However, when I execute the endpoint, I get a **org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:** error.

I have tried to make sure that the text and file parameters are correctly being received, and have inspected the payload coming in with the following code

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
fun upload(input:MultipartFormDataInput) {
    var map = input.getFormDataMap()
    map.entries.forEach {
        println("""${it.key} - ${it.value}""") 
        if (it.value is List<InputPart>) {
            it.value.forEach { ip ->
                println(""" --- ${ip.getMediaType()} """ ) 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And it correctly says

```
text - [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl@660c4317]
 --- text/plain;charset=UTF-8
file - [org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.providers.multipart.MultipartInputImpl$PartImpl@3aee346]
 --- application/octet-stream;charset=UTF-8
```

I assume there is something going wrong with the FormData class that RestEasy isn't automagically mapping to it. I have tried changing the type for "file" to be ByteArray and File, and they both fail also.

I have struggled to find Kotlin specific answers, so it is possible this is a Kotlin oddity also.

Answer (score 2):

I just went through this issue, showing no logs at all. I managed to make it work, it seems that a empty constructor is required :

```
class FormData() {
    @FormParam("text") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    var text: String? = null

    @FormParam("file") @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) 
    var file: InputStream? = null
}
```

However I must still be missing something because

```
class FormData(
    @FormParam("text") @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) var text: String?,
    @FormParam("file") @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM) var file: InputStream?
) {
    constructor() : this(null, null)
}
```

enters in the method but doesn't init values

Edit: after testing secondary constructors and primary constructors like this working one,

```
class FormData
{
    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    var file: InputStream? = null

    constructor() {
        this.file = null
    }

}
```

It seems that an EMPTY PRIMARY CONSTRUCTOR is required :)

Hope it helped !

Answer (score 1):

I won't mark this answer as correct, as I am not happy with the solution, but it at least works.

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
fun upload(input:MultipartFormDataInput) {
    val map = input.getFormDataMap()
    val text = map.get("text")?.first()?.getBodyAsString() ?: ""
    val file = map.get("file")?.first()?.getBodyAsString() ?: ""

    println(form.text)
    println(form.file)
}
```

As you can see, I am getting the data directly from the MultipartFormDataInput, rather than auto-constructing the object. Hopefully someone is able to shed some light on why this work around is needed, or whether a better solution is available.

Comment: As of Quarkus 2.2.3.Final, using a Kotlin class with empty constructor works. It also applicable to the latest async RestEasy @RestFrom annotation. Sadly, it doesn't work with data class yet.